# Google Apps Script function is executing twice if I remove ui.alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I have a function to extract all the image captions in a Google docs which is being called using a button in my Plug-in, the problem is when I comment the `ui.alert()` part the function is executing twice. The code is:

```js
function refFig() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  // var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // ui.alert('Inside the function');
  var images = body.getImages();
  var images_caption = [];
  var j = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    var linkString = image.getLinkUrl();
    if (linkString != null) {
      var caption = linkString.slice(15, linkString.length);
      var refUrl = '#D2L_fig_ref_' + caption;
      images_caption[j++] = refUrl;
    }
  }

  return images_caption;
}
```

The jquery used to call the function is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#refFig').click(call_refFig);
});

function call_refFig() {
  this.disabled = true;
  $('#error').remove();
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(after_refFig)
    .withFailureHandler(function(msg, element) {
      showError(msg, $('#button-bar'));
      element.disabled = false;
    }).refFig();
}
```

The HTML of the button is:

```html
<div id="div_refFig" style="padding-left:0px">
  <a id="refFig" href="#!" class="collection-item grey-text text-darken-3">
    <i class="material-icons d2ltheme left">find_replace</i>
    Refer
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that the ui part has anything to do with it. You may have attached 2 event listeners to your 'refFig' link. In this case, each of them fires off an event handler when you click it.

Comment: Even if thats the case (which it is not) the function should run twice even when i uncomment the ui part, but thats not happening. When i run the code with the ui.alert working, the function is running only once.

Comment: What makes you think the function runs twice? I recreated your example and everything seems to be working as expected. The only caveat is that calling ui.alert() will destroy the ui container for your button (provided it's a dialog window as well). What do you use as a container for your client-side code?

Comment: i thought the function is running twice but the problem was with the success handler after_refFig() which was running twice. Anyway thanks a lot for your help :)